# Ошибка в Unity CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to create a raw.ap_package

Tags: unity3d

При билде программы для android появляется ошибка из за которой не компилируется проект а именно:
[image: Окно с ошибкой]

Сам же unity выводит такие ошибки:
[image: Ошибки]

Интересует первая ошибка, вот что выводит в ней я закинул сюда:
https://pastebin.com/P5a7BU9w
Я так понял это из-за видео в папке StreamingAssets. Весит оно 1.50 Mb. В документации в unity я нашел только то, что вроде видео собирается в определенный пакет формата jar. Но как решить эту проблему я не нашел. Поэтому и пишу сюда. Я думаю за столько то времени подобные вопросы поднимались и решались, но мне решение найти не удалось. SDK Tools использую версии 25.2.5

Comment: какая у Вас jdk установлена? (cmd.exe -> java -version)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ 1.8.0_202

Comment: там ошибка в том что класс не найден это значит что в папке с зависимостями что то не то, либо не хватает .jar либо 2 версии разные одной и той же либы.